# How can I add a timestamp to my CSS file and preload the file?

Tags: joomla-4.x, css, index.php

I have this code at the top of my index.php file to add a timestamp to my CSS file so that latest version is always rendered.

```
$version = filemtime(JPATH_THEMES . '/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css');
JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'template.css', array('version' => $version, 'relative' => true));
```

However, I would also like to preload the file and can't work out how to add `rel="preload"` and `as="style"` and `onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"` to the above.

Comment: I have heard this technique called a "cache buster".

Comment: Quite possibly. But when I've made changes to a CSS file I need them to be displayed on the front-end straight away, not in a month's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla 4 you can use the WebAsset Manager instead of HTMLHelper(JHtml).

In your template's *index.php* file:

```
$wa  = $this->getWebAssetManager();

$version = filemtime(JPATH_ROOT . '/media/templates/site/mytemplate/css/mymain.css');

$wa->registerAndUseStyle('template.mytemplate.mymmain', "mymain.css", ['version' => $version, 'relative' => true], ['rel' => "preload", 'as' => "style", 'onload' => "this.rel='stylesheet'" ], []);
```

in this example code, my css file is called: ***mymain.css*** and it is in **media** folder under *templates/site/mytemplate/css* subfolder as it should be. This has worked for me.

It is same with HTMLHelper:

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

$version = filemtime(JPATH_ROOT . '/media/templates/site/mytemplate/css/mymain.css');

HTMLHelper::stylesheet('mymain.css', $options = ['version' => $version, 'relative' => true, ], $attribs = ['rel' => "preload", 'as' => "style", 'onload' => "this.rel='stylesheet'"]);
```

result:

```
<link href="/media/templates/site/mytemplate/css/mymain.css?1681564883" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this several times unsuccessfully, but then I removed ```->useStyle('template.mytemplate')``` from ```$wa->useStyle('template.mytemplate')
 ->useStyle('template.user')
 ->useScript('template.user');``` it worked. I think in Cassiopeia the equivalent is ```>usePreset('template.cassiopeia.' . ($this->direction === 'rtl' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'))```

Comment: @Gillian -  Sure, for me both of my examples work without any problem. But the question was about how to add timestamp and attributes to stylesheet links…

Comment: Of course. I added my comment in case anyone else tried and had the same difficulty I did and could see why. I'll accept your answer.